# How to detect deadlocks in a Go program?

Tags: go, deadlock

In the below 2 programs, all existing go-routines are blocked.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func worker() {

    fmt.Printf("some work\n")

}

func main() {

    ch := make(chan int)

    go worker()
    <-ch

}
```

---

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "runtime"
    "sync"
)

func main() {

    // wg is used to manage concurrency
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(2)

    fmt.Println("Start Goroutines")

    // Create a goroutine from the lowercase function
    go func() {
        lowercase()
        // wg.Done() // Line 25
    }()

    // Create a goroutine from the uppercase function
    go func() {
        uppercase()
        wg.Done()
    }()

    // Wait for the goroutines to finish
    // fmt.Printf("Waiting for Finish")
    wg.Wait()    // Line 42

    fmt.Println("\n Terminating program")
}

// lowercase displays the set of lowercase letters three times
func lowercase() {

    // Display the alphabet three times
    for count := 0; count < 3; count++ {
        for r := 'a'; r <= 'z'; r++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", r)
        }
    }
}

// uppercase displlays the set of uppercase letters three times.
func uppercase() {

    // Display the alphabet three times
    for count := 0; count < 3; count++ {
        for r := 'A'; r <= 'Z'; r++ {
            fmt.Printf("%c ", r)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
$ go version
go version go1.20.2 linux/amd64
$ go build   -o main cmd/test/main.go
$ go run -race cmd/test/main.go
some work
^Csignal: interrupt
$
```

Does Go compiler provide flag options to detect deadlock?

Comment: The inbuilt deadlock detector should pick up the issue in both examples (no flags needed - [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/nysmCD0O6lK) &  [playground](https://go.dev/play/p/DqFVtAEUj7q)). Note that the detector is not perfect (that would require a solution to the [halting problem](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)) and may be disabled [for a range of reasons](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/29322).

Comment: `go run -race cmd/test/main.go` try without the race detector (that is one of the things that might [prevent deadlock detection](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/20588)).

Comment: Go run will throw deadlock error when you run the program -- I use golang 1.20, like there: `fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!`

Comment: To be clear, you can't rely on deadlock detection, because complete detection can not exist (as Brits pointed out, it would require solving the Halting Problem). It's nice that it triggers in simple cases, but simple cases are all that's possible.